# Ставится ли запятая после оборота с "после"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в предложении?

> После опытов отца над ним между ними складываются плохие отношения.

Можно подробнее?

Answer (score 2):

Запятая не нужна. После оборотов с ***после*** запятую не ставят, за исключением случаев, когда без запятой непонятен смысл (можно трактовать двояко).

Comment: @shampar: спасибо за "двояко"! Так действительно лучше.

Comment: Как говорят у их — красивше.